# CXF - Memory leak occurs if a bus configured with providers is used by per-request clients

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, tomcat7, cxf, rest-client

**CXF Component/s**:    Bus, JAX-RS

**Affects Version/s**:    3.1.0, 3.1.6

**Environment**:    Redhat Enterprise Linux (Santiago), OpenJDK 7, Tomcat 7

We have an application with REST client components for making calls to Backend web services. During our routine performance test, JProfiler tool shows lots of Bus property entries (with keys named "bus.providers.set.") populated while creating instances of ClientProviderFactory.

```
public final class ClientProviderFactory extends ProviderFactory {

    public static ClientProviderFactory createInstance(Bus bus) {
    ...
    factory.setBusProviders();
    ...
}
```

These Bus property entries seem to stay in heap for the whole duration of the 6 hour run. In fact, around 100,000 entries occupying 13 MB of heap.
In short, GC doesn't seem to happening frequently enough to keep the heap usage within limits.

Is this some sort of a bug or, lack of necessary configuration in CXF to optimize the creation/cleanup of these objects?

Answer (score 2):

The concerned issue seems to be caused by [a defect in CXF](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6938) where the ProviderFactory hashCode entries are populated on the Bus instance if per-request clients are used. So, if you have made N calls since application startup, N number of entries will be populated. Hence, it occupies huge JVM heap and doesn't get GC, in time and leads to performance issues.

Although the CXF fix for the defect will be available in snapshot releases - 3.1.7 and 3.2.0, you can use the following work-around fix if you are stuck with using CXF 3.1.6 or, older. It works like a charm.

**Java code**

```
public class PurgeFactoryHashcodeInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> { 

    public PurgeFactoryHashcodeInterceptor() { 

        super(Phase.PREPARE_SEND); 
        addBefore(MessageSenderInterceptor.class.getName()); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault { 

            cleanUpBusProperties(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void handleFault(Message message) throws Fault { 

            cleanUpBusProperties(); 
    } 

    private void cleanUpBusProperties() { 

        Bus bus =    SpringContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(Bus.class); 
        Map<String,Object> origBusPropMap = bus.getProperties(); 

        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> busPropEntry : origBusPropMap.entrySet()) { 
            if(busPropEntry.getKey().startsWith("bus.providers.set.")) { 
                origBusPropMap.remove(busPropEntry.getKey()); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

**Spring configuration**

```html
<bean id="purgeFtryHashcodeInterceptor" class="com.mycompany.ws.interceptor.PurgeFactoryHashcodeInterceptor" />
  
<cxf:bus>
       <cxf:properties>
           <entry key="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.bus.providers">
               <list>
                   <ref bean="throwableExceptionMapper" />
                   <ref bean="customFilter1" />
               </list>
           </entry>
       </cxf:properties>
       <cxf:outInterceptors>
           <ref bean="purgeFtryHashcodeInterceptor" />
       </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

Comment: Don't forget to vote me up, if you had come across the same issue.